# Mule 4 response naming and extension configuration

Tags: mulesoft

Here I am getting a response from my api but the thing is I am getting(downloading) the file by the name  **CAT-L489-H342** which is without any extension.
What I want the response name to be like this **Datasheet-CAT-L489-H342.pdf** as I am getting the response in the form of pdf which is downloading too.

Can anyone help me in this situation?

I tried using Content-Type= application/pdf

actual- CAT-L489-H342
expected- Datasheet-CAT-L489-H342.pdf

Comment: Did you check for file extension and/or file name in SFTP/FTP , or any variable defined ?

Comment: It will not work as I don't have any specific host and port, it is like a download button on a web page and when the user hits that download button it will download the pdf and the name of the file must be like this Datasheet-id.pdf(ex- Datasheet-CAT-L489-H342.pdf)